# I am loading a web view in UIWebView, I need to click on the login button on the website

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am loading a web view in UIWebView, I need to click on the login button on the website. When the login button is clicked, The login form opens in a model. What I need is when my webview loads the model should already be opened by default.

This is the login button on the webpage that displays the form in the model.

[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Atif Javed on 30/12/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Atif Javed. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {

   @IBOutlet weak var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!
   @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // myWebView.delegate = self;
     // loadAddress()
     loader.hidesWhenStopped = true
     myWebView.delegate = self

     loadAddress()
   }

   func loadAddress(){
     let url=URL(string:"URL_HERE");
     myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url!))
   }

   func webView(_ myWebView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
     loader.startAnimating()
     return true
   }

   func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ myWebView: UIWebView) {
     loader.stopAnimating()
   }

   func webView(_ myWebView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
     loader.stopAnimating()
   }
 }
```

Comment: Be little more specific about what u need. I could not make any sense out of your question. One general suggestion use WKWebView rather than UIWebView

Comment: I have a splash and after the splash I have  UIWebView. the website that needs to be viewed in that has a login button on the homepage, upon clicking that button the login form appears in a model. What I wannt to is. I need to load the login model by default so that when the WebView Loads, its login model should be open by default. So, that the user dont have to click the login button. I hope it makes sense now.!

Answer (score 1):

Add onload to the body of your HTML

```
<body onload="login()">
```

Then your login function will be called when your HTML loads.
Display your login form within the login() method.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, The website is not mine so I cant make changes to it. Please suggest another way.

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea:
Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be easier to...

1. Create a native view with a login form in the app.
2. Create a POST URLRequest with the credentials from the login form.
3. Let the WebView load the request.

Example:

```
let postRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
// set credentials on postRequest
myWebView.loadRequest(postRequest)
```

This will load the website and the user is already logged-in.
Additionally the user can use a native login form, that might be easier to use than the webform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Okay, I will create a login form and When the user clicks the login button, on button click the request will be sent. What will do next? or the URL of the webView will be the POST request?

Comment: @AtifJaved I added a small example. Usually the post request of a webform returns the site where the user is already logged-in. If that it the case, I would recommend to let the webView run the POST request, since the response would be already the website you want to present after the login.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. but still getting the homepage. That's the website.
https://agri-logix.net/ that has the issue.

 func loadAddress(){
        let url=URL(string:"https://agri-logix.net/");
//        myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url!))
        
        var postRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "input_0=atifjvd1@gmail.com&input_1=admin123"
        postRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        myWebView.loadRequest(postRequest)
    }

Comment: That postString looks more like URL parameters than the body. So you might need to send them as headerFields.   `postRequest.addValue("atifjvd1@gmail.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "input_0")`. If you are in doubt ask the developer who implemented the login on the website.

Comment: I have tried that way as well still the user is not logged in. Did you check the website? how its sending the post request. as I am unable to figure this out.

' func loadAddress(){
        let url=URL(string:"https://agri-logix.net/");
        var postRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        postRequest.addValue("atifjvd1@gmail.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "input_0")
            postRequest.addValue("admin123", forHTTPHeaderField: "input_1")
        
        myWebView.loadRequest(postRequest)
    }'

Comment: Read the docs for URLRequest and talk back to the developer of the website. If you have a **specific question**, create another one on StackOverflow, since the login mechanism of the website has nothing to do with your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a solution to you.

According to my understanding. You have load the login form in the web view after splash.

So I can suggest you to convert all  HTML form into the HTMLstring then you have to store that string into the localDB (you may use CoreData / user defaults)
So after the splash is ended and webview is loaded.
Then whole HTML page is available offline and access directly.

This will load into smaller interval of time 
Make sure you have allow the links in your web view.
And your HTML page have **inline CSS**,so that it should look good ,

This will definitely works !!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I don't have access to the website. The website loads the login form in a model upon clicking the login button on the website. What I want is when after the splash screen finished. I need to open the login model by default in the webview.

Comment: Thanks , now I would suggest you to look at the URL link which you would be obtain after clicking on the login button on website.  This would be easier to locate the Login Model with the help of the URL link.  And load that link in  your webview. Hope I am clear with my point. Please let me know if you have any query